# Save list into list

Tags: python, list

I have results of an function that is saved into a list. To return these values I want to put them into an array inside the for loop.

```
illResults = [0 for i in range(sizeC), 0 for i in range(sizeH)]
for c in range(1, sizeC+1):
    ...
    for h in range(1, sizeH+1):
        ...
        results = [x, y, e]
        illResults[c,h] = results # FAILS
```

What needs to be changed to save the multidimensional results in another multidimensional lists? Or would one do this completely different?

Note: I am using Ironpython and thus can not make use of numpy.

Comment: Hard to understand what you asking. Seriously,hard.

Comment: `illResults[c,h]` is a `TypeError` it must be `illResults[c][h]` !

Comment: If you're not using NumPy then you are using `list`s not `array`s.  The difference matters.

Comment: @Kasra It's a valid sytax, but not what OP wants.

Comment: Why would that be invalid syntax? Saving a complete array in a single array element would be achieved in C/C++ with pointers and in Matlab (which uses Pointers) using a Cell. I want to achieve the same in python.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech its a  `TypeError `, if you add it python assume it as a tuple and raise the following error  `list indices must be integers, not tuple`  !

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary actually its `TypeError ` !

Answer (score 0):

You could construct the list (because what you deem an array is called list in python) using a list comprehension.

for example:

```
[[some_func(x, y) for x in xrange(sizeC)] for y in xrange(sizeH)]
```

(where `some_func` can be just about any function (or expression) you can write in python)

Comment: I do not understand he usage of this. What is the dimension of this array? for what do I need some_func?

Comment: The resulting value is a list of lists (or in your words a 2-dimensional array). some_func(x, y) is just a placeholder, e.g. if you want to fill the list with zeroes, you'd just use [[0 for x in xrange(sizeC)] for y in xrange(sizeH)]. I just included it to show that you can do arbitrary calculations in there.